# using pipe async always stucks on loading

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, switchmap, combinelatest

I'm joining multiple observables in one global `joined$` observable using `switchMap` and `combineLatest`

this is the **component TS file**:

```
export class ProgressComponent implements OnInit{

    user: User;
    joined$: Observable<any>;

    constructor(
        protected tasksService: TasksService,
        protected courseService: CoursesService,
        protected fieldService: FieldsService,
        protected sessionService: SessionsService,
        protected applicationService: ApplicationForSessionsService,
        protected TaskdatesService: SessionTaskDatesService,
        protected router: Router,
        private userStore: UserStore)
    {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.user = this.userStore.getUser();
        this.joined$ = this.applicationService.list(1, 10, undefined, this.user.id)
            .pipe(
                switchMap(applications => {
                    const courseSessionIds = uniq(applications.map(application => application.courseSessionId))

                    return combineLatest(
                        of(applications),
                        combineLatest(
                            courseSessionIds.map(courseSessionId => this.sessionService.get(courseSessionId).pipe(
                                switchMap(session => {
                                    const courseId = session.courseId
                                    return combineLatest(
                                        of(session),
                                        combineLatest(
                                            this.courseService.get(courseId).pipe(
                                                switchMap(course => {
                                                    const fieldId = course.fieldId

                                                    return combineLatest(
                                                        of(course),
                                                        combineLatest(
                                                            this.fieldService.get(fieldId).pipe(
                                                                map (field => field)
                                                            )
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                }),
                                                map(([course, field]) => {
                                                    return {...course, field: field.find(f => f.id == course.fieldId)}
                                                })
                                            )
                                        ),
                                                                         
                                    )
                                }),
                                map(([session, course]) =>  {
                                    return {
                                        ...session, 
                                        course: course.find(c => c.id === session.courseId)
                                    }
                                }),
                                switchMap( session => {
                                    const sessionId = session.id;

                                    return combineLatest(
                                        of(session),
                                        combineLatest(
                                            this.TaskdatesService.getBySessionId(sessionId).pipe(
                                                switchMap(dates => {
                                                    const taskDatesIds = uniq(dates.map(dt => dt.taskId));

                                                    return combineLatest(
                                                        of(dates),
                                                        combineLatest(
                                                            taskDatesIds.map(taskDateId => this.tasksService.get(taskDateId).pipe(
                                                                map(task => task)
                                                            ))
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                }),
                                                map(([dates, task]) => {
                                                    return dates.map(date => {
                                                        return {...date, task: task.find(t => t.id === date.taskId)}
                                                    })
                                                
                                                })
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                }),
                                map(([session, dates]) => {
                                    return {
                                        ...session,
                                        dates: dates.map(date => date.find(d => d.sessionId === session.id))
                                    }
                                })
                            ))
                        )
                    )
                }),
                map(([applications, session]) => {
                    return applications.map(app => {
                        return {
                            ...app,
                            session: session.find(s => s.id === app.courseSessionId)
                        }
                    })
                })
            );
    }
}
```

And here is the **HTML template file**

```
    <ng-container *ngIf="joined$ | async; else loading; let joined">

    <div *ngFor="let application of joined">
        <div class="current-application">
            <nb-card>
                <nb-card-header>
                    <h4>{{application.session.course.name}}</h4>
                    <small><i>{{application.session.course.field.name}}</i></small>
                </nb-card-header>
                <nb-card-body>
                    <p><b>id: </b>{{application.id}}</p>
                    <p><b>applicationDate: </b>{{application.applicationDate}}</p>
                    <p><b>acceptedDate: </b>{{application.acceptedDate}}</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p><b>session Id: </b>{{application.session.id}}</p>
                    <p><b>session capacity: </b>{{application.session.capacity}}</p>
                    <p><b>session startDate: </b>{{application.session.startDate}}</p>
                    <p><b>session endDate: </b>{{application.session.endDate}}</p>
                    <hr>
                    <p><b>Course Id: </b>{{application.session.course.id}}</p>
                    <p><b>Course Id: </b>{{application.session.course.id}}</p>
                </nb-card-body>
            </nb-card>
        </div>
    </div>

</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>
    <p>Loding ...</p>
</ng-template>
```

**Edit:** After debugging I found that the error occurs when **Dates array** is empty, so the solution consists of applying a test for the length of the dates array. The problem is when I try to make a condition I got the following error

> Argument of type '(dates: SessionTaskDate[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: SessionTaskDate[], index: number) => ObservableInput'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.

triggered in the following:

```
switchMap(dates =>{
        if(dates.length > 0){
            dates.map(date => this.augmentDateWithTask(date))
        }
    })
```

Comment: this is way too much code. At first glance: I don't think you should use switchmap inside a combinelatest (use it after the combineLates, and you don't have to do of(session) when your session value is already available,  just to name a few problems

Comment: This code is very complicated and hard to follow.  I'd suggest breaking it up into smaller pieces.  If your template is always stuck on loading, then it's because `joined$` never emits a value.  When using `combineLatest`, it will not emit any values until all of its source observables emit, so that might be your problem.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `of` and `combineLatest`.  They are both functions that generate an observable.  `combineLatest` is used when you have 2 or more source observables.  In your case, it seems that you only have a single source, `applicationService.list()`.  So it seems you don't really need `combineLatest` at all.

Comment: I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@joaqcid/how-to-inner-join-data-from-multiple-collections-on-angular-firebase-bfd04f6b36b7) I just need to inner join those entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you have a series of *applications* which are notified by the Observable returned by `this.applicationService.list`.

Then each *application* has a *courseSessionId* which you can use to fetch course session details via `this.sessionService.get` method.

Then each *session* has a *courseId* which you can use to fetch *course* details via `this.courseService.get`.

Then each *course* has a *fieldId* which you can use to fetch *field* details via `this.fieldService.get`.

Now you should have an array of *sessions* containing also all details of the *course* they refer to.

Then, for each *session*, you need to fetch the *dates* via `this.TaskdatesService.getBySessionId`.

*Dates* seems to be objects containing a *taskDatesId*. You collect all *taskDatesIds* and fetch *task* details via `this.tasksService.get`.

Now that you have all *dates* and all *tasks*, for each *date* you create a new object with *date* properties and its related *task*.

Then you go back to the *session* you create a new object with all *session* properties and its related *dates*.

Now you have an object with all *session* details, all details of the *course* it refers to and all the details of the *dates* it has.

The last step is to create, for each *application*, a new object containing all properties of the *application* plus all properties of the "augmented" *session* object just created.

Quite some logic.

So, again, if this is the correct understanding, I would approach the problem from the most inner requests outwards.

The first inner request is the one that, starting from a *course* returns an Observable which emits an object with all *course* properties and the *field* details (let's call this object an *augmentedCourse*). This could be performed by a method like this

```
augmentCourseWithField(course) {
  return this.fieldService.get(course.fieldId).pipe(
    map (field => {
      return {...course, field}
    })
  )
}
```

Then I would make a step outwards and would create a method that, starting from a *courseId*, returns an Observable which emits an *augmentedCourse*, i.e. an object with all the *course* and the *field* details.

```
fetchAugmentedCourse(courseId) {
  return this.courseService.get(courseId).pipe(
     switchMap(course => this.augmentCourseWithField(course))
  )
}
```

Now let's do a further step outwards, and create a method that, starting from a *session*, returns an object with all properties of the *session* plus the properties of the *augmentedCourse* the *session* refers to. Let's call this object *augmentedSession*.

```
augmentSessionWithCourse(session) {
  return this.fetchAugmentedCourse(session.courseId).pipe(
    map(course => {
      return {...session, course}
    })
  )
}
```

Now one more step outwards. We want to fetch an *augmentedSession* starting from a *courseSessionId*.

```
fetchAugmentedSession(courseSessionId) {
  return this.sessionService.get(courseSessionId).pipe(
     switchMap(session => this.augmentSessionWithCourse(session))
  )
}
```

So, what did we achieve so far? We are able to create an Observable which emits an *augmentedSession* starting from a *courseSessionId*.

At the outermost level though we have a list of *applications*, each of which contains a *courseSessionId*. Different *applications* can share the same *course* and so have the same *courseSessionId*. Therefore it makes sense to fetch all *applications*, create a list of unique *courseSessionIds*, use such list to fetch all the *courses* and then assign to each *application* its *course*. In this way we avoid querying the back end more than once for the same course.

This can be acheived like this

```
fetchAugmentedApplications(user) {
  return this.applicationService.list(1, 10, undefined, user.id).pipe(
    switchMap(applications => {
      const courseSessionIds = uniq(applications.map(application => application.courseSessionId));
      // create an array of Observables, each one will emit an augmentedSession
      const augSessObs = courseSessionIds.map(sId => fetchAugmentedSession(sId))
      // we can use combineLatest instead of forkJoin, but I prefer forkJoin
      return forkJoin(augSessObs).pipe(
        map(augmentedSessions => {
          return applications.map(app => {
            const appSession = augmentedSessions.find(s => s.id === app.courseSessionId);
            return {...app, session: appSession}
          });
        })
      )
    })
  )
}
```

With a similar style you should be able to add also *dates* details to your *sessions*. Also in this case we start with innermost operation, which is to retrieve an array of *tasks* given an array of *taskIds* via `his.tasksService.get`.

The code would look like this

```
fetchTasks(taskIds) {
   taskObs = taskIds.map(tId => this.tasksService.get(tId));
   return forkJoin(taskObs)
}
```

Moving one step outward, we can augment each *date* of an array of *dates* with *tasks* that belong to that *date* like this

```
augmentDates(dates) {
  if (dates.length === 0) {
    return of([]);
  }
  const taskDatesIds = uniq(dates.map(dt => dt.taskId));
  return fetchTasks(taskDatesIds).pipe(
    map(tasks => {
      return dates.map(date => {
        return {...date, task: task.find(t => t.id === date.taskId)}
      })
    })
  )
}
```

Now we can augment a *session* with its *dates* like this

```
augmentSessionWithDates(session) {
  return this.TaskdatesService.getBySessionId(session.id).pipe(
    switchMap(dates => augmentDates(dates).pipe( 
      map(augmentedDates => {
        return {...session, dates: augmentedDates};
      })
    ))
  )
}
```

We can now complete the `fetchAugmentedSession` method, adding also the part that augment the *session* with *dates* info like this

```
fetchAugmentedSession(courseSessionId) {
  return this.sessionService.get(courseSessionId).pipe(
     switchMap(session => this.augmentSessionWithCourse(session)),
     switchMap(session => this.augmentSessionWithDates(session)),
  )
}
```

In this way you have split your logic in smaller chunks, which are easier to test and, hopefully, easier to read.

I did not have any playground to test the code, so it is very well possible that there are typos in it. I hope though that the logic is clear enough.

Comment: Thank you, your method clarified a lot of things, the only problem that the final augmented applications observable is working fine if I remove the Dates array part.

I found it easier to create the field and course because they are only an attribute in the object. the main problem was with the Dates[] array

Comment: the problem if fired when the dates array is empty. I have no idea how to apply a condition on it, see the edit

Comment: The point is that the function you pass to `switchMap` as parameter must return an Observable. In your code, in case `dates` is empty you return `void` hence the error. I try to edit my response with a suggestion for this case.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of async nesting, perhaps there is another way to go about this?

If you are trying to take multiple observables and have a single subscription (say, be able to react to a number of events in a similar manner), then use rxjs **merge.**

If you are wanting to do a lot of individual subscriptions, like subscribe to users, foo, and bar and then use all of their values for some logic, use rxjs **forkJoin.**

If you state a clear objective it would be easier to offer guidance, but I know that level of rxjs operator nesting is not easily maintained.

Comment: all I need is to get the data from 5 different entities joined in a specific structure to present it in the template after applying minor logic on it. the code I have written is inspired from this [article](https://medium.com/@joaqcid/how-to-inner-join-data-from-multiple-collections-on-angular-firebase-bfd04f6b36b7)

Comment: depending on how you need things structured, I still feel you should be able to just do one large combineLatest.

similar to:
combineLatest(timerOne$, timerTwo$, timerThree$).subscribe(
  ([timerValOne, timerValTwo, timerValThree]) => {

see https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest

Comment: the code above works fine if I exclude the part of the dates array, also when I applied the solution to the other question I face the same problem. also, the other answer is explaining the logic more then I did.

Comment: the problem if fired when the dates array is empty. I have no idea how to apply a condition on it, see the edit